# Missing plugin exception in Flutter while implementing platform specific code

Tags: android, flutter

While implementing platform specific code for Android I faced the following error.

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception:
> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method
> getTemporaryDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this issue while implementing platform specific code. I want to share my experience in this case.

First clean the project using

```
flutter clean
```

Then upgrade the plugins using

```
flutter pub get
```

Then run project(Not hot reload. Plugins will inject codes)

```
flutter run
```

If the problem persist again, you may be missing

> GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)

which you have to place here

```
override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    //***HERE***
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, BEACON_ACTIVATE_CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler{
        call, result ->
        when {
            call.method.equals("yourMethodName") -> {
                yourNativeFunction(call, result)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related, but do you mind sharing your beacon implementation? I've been having trouble setting up background monitoring. EDIT: only android is not working properly