# Persisting MissingPluginException in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Hello developers of the world!

I have a persisting issue with using a specific Flutter package for Android and iOS.

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getTemporaryDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

This raises when I use a function of **audioplayers** (https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers).

This is not a story of hot restart. I also tried the solution proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66593064/8791925 but I got no improvement.

The content of my MainActivity.kt is

```kotlin
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

Edit:

I add the content of the pubspec.yaml concerning dependencies

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  # region firebase
  firebase_core: "^1.7.0"
  firebase_database: "^8.0.0"
  cloud_firestore: "^2.5.3"
  firebase_messaging: "^10.0.8"
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.3
  firebase_auth_platform_interface: ^6.1.1
  firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.0.1
  # endregion
  flutter_signin_button: ^2.0.0
  # region internationalisation
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.17.0
  # endregion

  # region notification
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.1.5
  awesome_notifications: any
  flutter_native_timezone: ^2.0.0
  # endregion
  http: ^0.13.0

  shared_preferences: ^2.0.7

  uuid: ^3.0.5

  device_info: ^2.0.2

  # region bloc
  flutter_bloc: ^7.3.1
  # endregion

  formz: ^0.4.0
  cache:
    path: packages/cache
  equatable:

  flutter_slidable:
  animations:

  # region qr code
  qr_code_scanner: ^0.6.1
  # endregion

  # region audio and sound
  audioplayers: ^0.20.1
  path_provider:
  volume_control: ^0.1.5
  volume: ^1.0.1
  # endregion

  # region connectivity
  connectivity_plus: "^0.0.1"
  # endregion





dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

I also add the content of the Android Manifest

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="...">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:label="..."
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        tools:targetApi="m">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:turnScreenOn="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:targetApi="o_mr1">

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
           android:value="FIREBASE_NOTIF_ID"/>

        <service
            android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ForegroundService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Do you see what I can be missing?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just to make sure, you did a hot RESTART? A hot reload is not enough, especially when you are using a package which uses native code (a plugin), since it needs to be compiled first to work correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I mean this is a problem that persist through weeks and yes I restarted several times and recompiled the code.

Comment: Are you using it on FlutterWeb?

Comment: Try adding `path_provider` to your pubspec. Does this change anything?

Comment: @JahnE, no it's for Android and iOS only and it is currently tested on Android.

Comment: @RichardHeap, I added this package to pubspec.yaml but it does not change anything.

Comment: Does your `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.kt or java` file show that the dependency has added code similar to this? `flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin());`

Comment: @RichardHeap yes, it does

Comment: If you create a new, empty project and add a dependency on just `path_provider` does it then compile and work (e.g. you can print the result of getTemporaryDirectory)

Comment: @RichardHeap, on a new empty project, `getTemporaryDirectory().then((value) => print(value));` prints a coherent value. So yes, it works as you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

I finally found the solution: **upgrading packages** (`flutter pub upgrade`). By chance, the issue was fixed by maintainers of `path_provider`. I was in version 2.0.10 when the issue occurs and the version 2.0.11 fixes it.

### Explanation

I tried to do this but only in December, when I got the issue for the first time and it did not solve it at this time.

To understand the origin of the fix, I checked which packages were updated in pubspec.lock. I saw that `path_provider_android` was updated and not `path_provider` became 'transitive':

```yaml
  path_provider:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.8"
  path_provider_android:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider_android
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.11"
```

Then:

- I searched when `path_provider_android` was last updated through the package manager https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider_android,
- I went to the code https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/path_provider/path_provider_android,
- I checked git history https://github.com/flutter/plugins/commits/master/packages/path_provider/path_provider_android,
- and the message explains the fix https://github.com/flutter/plugins/commit/6a9de4f5a7c03cf24418febe01d9bfe09bdcc40b#diff-119886b649d8227f96835751fa3ad592ee6914cf12cc9525814d40b1a9480d5a,
- this corresponding issue was https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/95706 and this was also mine but I did not find it among the other issues mentioning the same one.